# Oracle Hierarchical Query at depth level

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, hierarchical-query

I have a requirement to build a table from a hierarchical table. Table structure as below:

**emp_hier table:**

| emp_id | supervisorId |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | null |
| 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |

**New table:**

I have to write a select query on the emp_heir table and the selected data should look like this:

| sel_emp_id | rel_emp_id | relation | depth_lvl |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 100 | self | 0 |
| 100 | 1 | My Repotee | -1 |
| 100 | 2 | My Repotee | -2 |
| 100 | 3 | My Repotee | -3 |
| 1 | 100 | My Mgr | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | self | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | My Repotee | -1 |
| 1 | 3 | My Repotee | -2 |
| 2 | 1 | My Mgr | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | self | 0 |
| 2 | 3 | My Repotee | -1 |
| 3 | 100 | My Mgr | 3 |
| 3 | 1 | My Mgr | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | My Mgr | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | self | 0 |

Comment: For employee 2, why is there no row for 100 as "My Mgr"? Other than that: first, why do you need the word "My" in those strings? (You don't, and it doesn't make sense; somebody else will read the report, not the employee himself. Mgr, Reportee and Self are quite sufficient.) And why does this need to be a table, and not just a **view**, so that it updates automatically when the data changes in the base table? Note also the "r" in the word "Repo**r**tee" which you are missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL` to combine a hierarchical query to get each row and its children to another hierarchical query to get all the ancestors:

```sql
SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT emp_id AS sel_emp_id,
       emp_id AS rel_emp_id,
       CASE LEVEL WHEN 1 THEN 'Self' ELSE 'My Reportee' END AS relation,
       1 - LEVEL AS depth_lvl
FROM   emp_hier
CONNECT BY PRIOR emp_id = supervisorid
UNION ALL
SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT emp_id,
       emp_id,
       'My Mgr',
       LEVEL - 1
FROM   emp_hier
WHERE  LEVEL > 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR supervisorid = emp_id
ORDER BY sel_emp_id, depth_lvl DESC
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE emp_hier (emp_id, supervisorId) AS
SELECT 100, null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1,   100  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,   1    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3,   2    FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | SEL_EMP_ID | REL_EMP_ID | RELATION | DEPTH_LVL |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 100 | My Mgr | 1 |
> | 1 | 1 | Self | 0 |
> | 1 | 2 | My Reportee | -1 |
> | 1 | 3 | My Reportee | -2 |
> | 2 | 100 | My Mgr | 2 |
> | 2 | 1 | My Mgr | 1 |
> | 2 | 2 | Self | 0 |
> | 2 | 3 | My Reportee | -1 |
> | 3 | 100 | My Mgr | 3 |
> | 3 | 1 | My Mgr | 2 |
> | 3 | 2 | My Mgr | 1 |
> | 3 | 3 | Self | 0 |
> | 100 | 100 | Self | 0 |
> | 100 | 1 | My Reportee | -1 |
> | 100 | 2 | My Reportee | -2 |
> | 100 | 3 | My Reportee | -3 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f0e3fbc7cdd6affc5f5254c61d85816f)*

Answer (score 0):

Using `CONNECT BY`, you can connect all the employees and their relationships to each other. Then by joining that information together, you can print out the information in the format you desire.

```sql
WITH
    hier
    AS
        (    SELECT e.*, LEVEL AS lvl
               FROM emp_hier e
         CONNECT BY PRIOR emp_id = supervisorid
         START WITH supervisorid IS NULL)
  SELECT h1.emp_id          AS sel_emp_id,
         h2.emp_id          AS rel_emp_id,
         CASE
             WHEN h1.lvl - h2.lvl = 0 THEN 'self'
             WHEN h1.lvl - h2.lvl > 0 THEN 'My Mgr'
             ELSE 'My Reportee'
         END                AS relation,
         h1.lvl - h2.lvl    AS depth_level
    FROM hier h1, hier h2
ORDER BY CASE WHEN h1.supervisorid IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, h1.emp_id, h1.lvl - h2.lvl DESC;



   SEL_EMP_ID    REL_EMP_ID       RELATION    DEPTH_LEVEL
_____________ _____________ ______________ ______________
          100           100 self                        0
          100             1 My Reportee                -1
          100             2 My Reportee                -2
          100             3 My Reportee                -3
            1           100 My Mgr                      1
            1             1 self                        0
            1             2 My Reportee                -1
            1             3 My Reportee                -2
            2           100 My Mgr                      2
            2             1 My Mgr                      1
            2             2 self                        0
            2             3 My Reportee                -1
            3           100 My Mgr                      3
            3             1 My Mgr                      2
            3             2 My Mgr                      1
            3             3 self                        0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the entire desired result with a single pass through the hierarchy (a single `CONNECT BY` query), with no self-join and no `union all`.

Instead, I use a helper inline view (with just one row and two numeric columns, with the values -1 and 1); since each "relationship" appears exactly twice in the output, with the exception of "Self", I use this to do an ad-hoc duplication of the rows from the hierarchical query.

I used the table in MT0's post for testing. I don't show the result - it's the same (just ordered differently).

```
with
  h (x) as (select  1 from dual union all select -1 from dual)
, p (ancestor, emp, depth) as (
    select  connect_by_root(emp_id), emp_id, level - 1
    from    emp_hier
    connect by supervisorid = prior emp_id
  )
select case h.x when 1 then emp      else ancestor end as emp_self,
       case h.x when 1 then ancestor else emp      end as emp_related,
       case when h.x      = 1 then 'Mgr'
            when p.depth != 0 then 'Reportee'
                              else 'Self'     end      as rel,
       h.x * p.depth                                   as depth_level
from   p join h on h.x = -1 or p.depth != 0   -- do not duplicate "Self"
order  by emp_self, depth_level desc, emp_related -- or whatever (if/as needed)
;
```